# Is $x^5-2x+4$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I was asked this question on my exam but I didn't know how to solve it. Eisenstein criterion can't be applied, rational roots theorem shows that it doesn't have a linear factor because possible roots are $\lbrace 1,-1,2,-2,4,-4 \rbrace$ and it doesn't seem to be irreducible over $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$ or $\mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z$

Comment: Slightly modified version of Eisenstein criterion works for this one, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3589657/prove-polynomial-is-irreducible/3590300#3590300.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $f(x)=x^5-2x+4$ has only one real root. By rational root test, $f(x)$ has no linear factor. If $f(x)$ is reducible, it must have a quadratic factor of the form $x^2+Ax+B,$ where $B$ divides $4$. But one has $A^2-4B<0$ and hence $B>0$, otherwise it will yield at least two real roots. There are just a few cases to consider.

Comment: The sum of coefficients in a proposed quadratic factor must also divide the sum of coefficients in the original quintic.  This plus your criterion leaves only these possibilities:  $x^2\pm x+1, x^2-2x+2, x^2+2$.

Comment: Good point! Perhaps possibly also $x^2-2x+4$.

Comment: Yes, I missed that.  Thanks.