# An irreducible polynomial in Z[x]

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p$ be a prime and let $n$ be an integer greater than $4$. Prove that if $a$ is an integer that is not divisible by $p$, then the polynomial
$$f(x)=ax^n-px^2+px+p^2$$is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

**Note.** I have proven that $f(x)=(bx+p)g(x)$, where $g(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $b \in \mathbb{Z}$. I have also proven that $|b|>1$.

Comment: @Peter I believe that Eisenstein's criterion cannot be used in this case, at least directly.

Comment: If your note is true, doesn’t that make $f(x)$ reducible?

Comment: Maybe that note is to be read is "if $f(x)$ were reducible, then ..." which would be true, the generalization of Eisenstein [mentioned here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3589657) shows that if $f(x)$ is reducible, it must have a linear factor (rational root)

Comment: @MaiVoPhucThanh I did not notice that we have $p^2$ as constant , sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a counterexample :

Let $p=2$ , $n=5$ , $a=1715$

Then $$f(x)=1715x^5-2x^2+2x+4$$ is divisible by $$7x+2$$

Comment: How did you find this counterexample?

Comment: Just brute force and PARI/GP. It is the only counterexample I found so far. For $p,a\le 10^4$ and $n\le 8$, there is no other one.

Comment: Nice, it seems that the original problem statement has a typo likely... I've checked with some negative $a$'s now and there is for example $p=3,n=5,a=-125$ (the statement does not explicitly probihit negative $a$'s)

Comment: @Sil You are right, my verification only included positive integers $a$. $$(2,5,-8019)$$ is another one.

Comment: @MaiVoPhucThanh If you are not sure whether your statement is correct, then you should not post a question such as "Prove that ...". This could potentially be a huge time waste for many people.

Comment: @WhatsUp This is in fact problem O134 in Mathematical Reflections Journal so I thought it is correct.

Comment: In that case it is prefered that you add a link to the source problem. Then all the complaining goes to that Journal.

Comment: @WhatsUp I'm truly sorry but the issue in which this problem was published is no longer available online so I can't add a link to that.

Comment: Then how can we tell whether you have miscopied the problem, so that it becomes a wrong statement while the original was correct?

Comment: @MaiVoPhucThanh So the original journal had just $a=1$ case? Then it would not be wrong... (only your generalization would)

Comment: @Sil Can you prove that with $a=1$ , we always have an irreducible polynomial ?

Comment: I think so, but I haven't worked out details (having linear factor and $a=1$ implies integer root dividing $p^2$, so we have only few possibilities), but note that OP has posted new question regarding this (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4274544/how-can-this-polynomial-become-irreducible) where they claim they can prove it for $a=\pm 1$ too

Comment: @Sil I could not find the generalized version of Eisenstein where we can conclude that the polynomial is irreducible or has a linear factor. Do you have a reference to this or can you demonstrate a proof here ?

Comment: @Peter It is the theorem I cite in this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3590300/290240, the article I referrence is this one (Theorem 1): https://www.lehigh.edu/~shw2/preprints/eisenstein.pdf. It tells us in this case the polynomial must have linear factor or be irreducible (since smallest coeff that is not divisible by $p^2$ is at $x^1$)